# How to get user ID from Facebook using token in Android

Tags: android

```
*I am easily getting a token from my app but when I am trying to get the ID or user ID, I can't.

    Facebook authenticatedFacebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);

After this I call the Facebook API and get a token.

    String token=data.getStringExtra("access_token");
    jsonobj=new JSONObject(authenticatedFacebook.request("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token="+token));

or

    jsonobj=new JSONObject(authenticatedFacebook.request("/me?access_token="+token));

or

    jsonobj=new JSONObject(authenticatedFacebook.request("me?access_token="+token));
    //  jsonresponseArray=jsonobj.getJSONArray("id");
    System.out.println("the id has"+jsonobj.has("id"));
String usrid=jsonobj.getString("id");
so it give me error that it doesn't have any id field.
So please, can you give me a solution? And thanks in advance.*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi by following lines you can do :

/me returns a JSON object with an id field (and others). You can parse this JSON object like this:

```
JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(facebook.request("me", params));
String userId = json.getString("id");
```

Comment: hey i just forget to add parameter in bundle so thanks to remember me